# Python: interpret expression as a text and not calculate it

Tags: python, sympy

After a working with SyMpy library I receive an expression (in **yprime** variable).

```
from sympy import *
x = Symbol('x')
y = 1 - (0.1 * coeff1) / (x + 2) - sin(x) * (2 * x + coeff1)
yprime = y.diff(x)
```

Then I try to use **yprime** in calculations, but Python interpret it as a text: **-(2*x + 1.0)*cos(x) - 2*sin(x) + 0.1/(x + 2)**2**

How may I calculate **-(2*x + 1.0)*cos(x) - 2*sin(x) + 0.1/(x + 2)**2** ?

After some manipulations according to [mtadd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/755875/mtadd):

```
from sympy import *
x, coeff1 = symbols('x coeff1')
y = 1 - (0.1 * coeff1) / (x + 2) - sin(x) * (2 * x + coeff1)
yprime = y.diff(x).evalf(subs={x:0,coeff1:1})
```

I receive a digital result, but still it's unable to operate with further logic. It says:

> TypeError: can't convert expression to float

Comment: Can you please be more specific about what code gives the TypeError? What you have should work.

Answer (score 2):

Call the method `subs` on your symbolic expression to calculate an analytic expression.  You can call `evalf` on the analytic expression to a numeric solution in a Python float.  Below is some example output from isympy after entering your input from above (coeff1 = 1.0).

```
In [18]: yprime
Out[18]:
                                   0.1
-(2⋅x + 1.0)⋅cos(x) - 2⋅sin(x) + ────────
                                        2
                                 (x + 2)

In [19]: yprime.subs(x,2*pi)
Out[19]:
                0.1
-4⋅π - 1.0 + ──────────
                      2
             (2 + 2⋅π)

In [20]: yprime.subs(x,2*pi).evalf()
Out[20]: -13.5649131254944
```

The following program:

```
from sympy import *
x, C1 = symbols('x C1')
y = 1-(0.1*C1)/(x+2)-sin(x)*(2*x+C1)
print y.diff(x).evalf(subs={x:pi/2,C1:1})
```

prints -1.99215722345589 with sympy version 0.7.2 and python 2.7.3.

Comment: Another valid expression is `yprime.evalf(subs={x:2*pi})`

Comment: Unfortunately, methods `subs` and `evalf` returns the same expression: **-(2*x + 1.0)*cos(x) - 2*sin(x) + 0.1/(x + 2)**2**

Comment: I'm working with sympy version 0.7.2, check your version with `import sympy; print sympy.__version__`

Comment: Mine too 0.7.2 and Python 2.7.

Comment: Try the 4 line script I added to the end of my answer above.

Comment: I can't even save **yprime** to file. It says: `TypeError: expected a character buffer object`

Comment: If you're using `write`, it expects a string.  Try write(str(yprime))

Comment: It may be due to a distinction between using the `Symbol` class constructor, and the `symbols` function that returns a tuple of multiple instantiations of said class. (note case of first letter).

Comment: In your original question, what is the type of `coeff1`?

Comment: after line 4 of your sample code, try to `print type(yprime)` and verify that its `sympy.core.add.Add` (basically its the root node of an AST).  If `type(yprime) == str`, then you'll need to convert it to a symbolic expression using `eval`: `eval(yprime).evalf(subs={x:1.5})`

Comment: I checked. It's class is `<class 'sympy.core.numbers.Float'>`.

Comment: Somewhere along the way `yprime` has been assigned with the `y.diff(x)` expression calculated for a particular value of x.

Comment: I updated description of the problem. Now I can't change 'digit' to real number.

Comment: I assume you're trying to cast something via the `float` function.  What is the object's type before attempting to cast it?

Comment: 'X' - int, 'coeff1' - float. That's all - I didn't used any other variables in this part of program.

Comment: try wrapping right hand side of last line with a call to `float`: e.g. `yprime = float(y.diff(x).evalf(subs={x:0,coeff1:1}))` afterwards, `type(yprime)` should be `float`

Comment: Sadly, the same error: **TypeError: can't convert expression to float**

Comment: That exception raises in `sympy.core.expr.Expr` class `__float__` method.  Unfortunately, I can't figure out why from here with the information I have.  try running the script with the python debugger enabled (_python -m pdb script.py_), and also look at the relevant python code in **site-packages/sympy/core/expr.py** (line 221)

Comment: Thanks for help. I'll try to figure it out by myself.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help [Evaluating a mathematical expression in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string) I think yprime is being interpreted as a string and this first answer of the post describes how to evaluate a string as an arithmetic expression.

Comment: It might, but it's a long and boring way. Probably there should be shorter way?